# How to make a login to a rest api with flask-security using requests

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-security

I have disabled CSRF but I can't get to login to a REST API using Flask-Security with roles based authorization, from a local front-end server. I do make the login but, I think, no cookies are stored on the request so I keep getting the login page on the front-end server. This is the code I am using:

```
 payload = {'username': request.form['username'], 'password': request.form['password']}
    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.post('http://localhost:5002/login', data=payload)
        print(s.cookies)
        if r.ok:
            r2 = s.get('http://localhost:5002/protected', cookies=s.cookies)
```

Is there a way to maintain the session to the front-end client that is logged in to show the protected content?

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass cookies to your second request. What happens if you remove `cookies=s.cookies`?

Comment: Still nothing, I get the login view

Comment: Does your `print(s.cookies)` print anything?

Comment: `<RequestsCookieJar[]>`

Comment: I can help you narrow down the problem, but I can't solve it with what you posted. All I can tell you is the `/login` page isn't setting any cookies on your session. That's why your second request fails the way it does.

Comment: I'm using the default login function from Flask-Security, do you have any idea of how to make it set the proper cookies?

Comment: Post the code for your `/login` endpoint - I might be able to help more if I see more code.

Comment: I don't have any code the `/login` endpoint, it uses the default endpoint from Flask-Security

Comment: What's the output of `print(r.status_code)`?

Comment: If you login in correctly - it will set a cookie. You don't need to pass s.cookies in the next time - requests.session does that for you. However - just checking r.ok doesn't mean you successfully logged in - so dump the response body. Finally - out-of-the-box Flask-Security doesn't have 'username' - it uses 'email' - so unless you have made some config changes (which we would need to see) my guess is you simply aren't authenticating correctly.

Comment: `print(r.status_code)` returns `200` I did changed the config to login with username instead of email

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but I agree with jwag that you're not authenticating correctly. Whether that's a bad config, or bad credentials, etc., I'm can't say for sure, but at the end of the day you're failing to properly authenticate.

Comment: You were completley right, bad config I solved it, thanks for helping me out

Comment: Do anyone happen to know how to share the sessions between the rest api and the front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flask-Security LoginForm does not accept 'username' - the field is called 'email'. Now - you CAN send in a username in that field, and if you have configured SECURITY_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES correctly - it should look up the column 'username' in the DB.

Second - I want to point out that just because you are using requests doesn't mean you are sending JSON - in fact you are sending a form input. So Flask-Security always responds with a form - you will basically never see anything other than a 200 - with the response body containing a 'form' that has the various error messages.

So - 2 things - if you want REST - do that - new versions of requests take an argument json= and will do the right thing. If you do that - you will start to get 400 responses I believe.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know how can I handle the cookies betwen the REST and the front-end? So they share them

Comment: It depends on your front-end - if it is browser based (e.g. Vue, react, etc) then of course the browser handles that. If you are doing server to server via ReST -then the requests session does it for you. Note that for server to server you might want to consider using the authentication token model instead of sessions.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little bit more, I am using server to server via REST